# Strip a part of string in linux

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Apps-10.00.00R000-B1111_vm-1.0.3-x86_64.qcow2 is my string and the result I want is vm-1.0.3

What is the best way to do this

Below is what I tried

```
$ echo Apps-10.00.00R000-B1111_vm-1.0.3-x86_64.qcow2 | awk -F _ {'print $2'} | awk -F - {'print $1,$2'}
```

vm 1.0.3

I also tried

```
$ echo Apps-10.00.00R000-B1111_vm-1.0.3-x86_64.qcow2 | awk -F _ {'print $2'} | awk -F - {'print $1"-",$2'}
```

vm- 1.0.3

Here I do not need space in between

I tried using cut and I got the expected result

```
$ echo Apps-10.00.00R000-B1111_vm-1.0.3-x86_64.qcow2 | awk -F _ {'print $2'} | cut -c 1-8
```

vm-1.0.3

What is the best way to do the same?

Comment: There's that script delimiters (`'`) inside a script body thing we see once in a while again - `{'...'}` instead of `'{...}'`. Where did you get the idea to do that - is there a book or tutorial out there suggesting it? It just showed up a couple of days ago at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/727086/133219 too but every time I ask where it comes from I never get an answer - frustrating!

Comment: @EdMorton I haven't used awk options for quite a while, it was just a inconsistency from my side maybe got too much used to syntax of other programming languages where the print statements will be `print(" ")`. I will never forget this again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 2 calls to awk, but your syntax with the single quotes outside the curly's, including printing the hyphen:

```
echo Apps-10.00.00R000-B1111_vm-1.0.3-x86_64.qcow2 | 
  awk -F_ '{print $2}' | awk -F- '{print $1 "-" $2}'
```

If your string has the same format, let the field separator be either `-` or `_`

```
echo Apps-10.00.00R000-B1111_vm-1.0.3-x86_64.qcow2 | awk -F"[-_]" '{print $4 "-" $5}'
```

Or split the second field on `-` and print the first 2 parts

```
echo Apps-10.00.00R000-B1111_vm-1.0.3-x86_64.qcow2 | awk -F_ '{
  split($2,a,"-")
  print a[1] "-" a[2]
}'
```

Or with `gnu-awk` a bit more specific match with a capture group:

```
echo Apps-10.00.00R000-B1111_vm-1.0.3-x86_64.qcow2 | 
  awk 'match($0, /^Apps-[^_]*_(vm-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/, a) {print a[1]}'
```

Output

```
vm-1.0.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Making assumptions from the 1 example you provided about what the general form of your input will be so it can handle that robustly, using any sed:

```
$ echo 'Apps-10.00.00R000-B1111_vm-1.0.3-x86_64.qcow2' |
    sed 's/^[^-]*-[^-]*-[^_]*_\(.*\)-[^-]*$/\1/'
vm-1.0.3
```

or any awk:

```
$ echo 'Apps-10.00.00R000-B1111_vm-1.0.3-x86_64.qcow2' |
    awk 'sub(/^[^-]+-[^-]+-[^_]+_/,"") && sub(/-[^-]+$/,"")'
vm-1.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest I can think of:

```
echo "Apps-10.00.00R000-B1111_vm-1.0.3-x86_64.qcow2" | cut -c 25-32
```

Obviously you need to be sure about the location of your characters. In top of that, you seem to be have two separators: '_' and '-', while both characters also are part of the name of your entry.

Comment: This seems to be pretty straight forward, but for some new releases the length might change.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo 'Apps-10.00.00R000-B1111_vm-1.0.3-x86_64.qcow2' | sed -E 's/^.*_vm-([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+)-.*/vm-\1.\2.\3/'
```

Comment: If you want those `.`s between the integers to be literal then you need to escape them, right now they'll match any character. There's no reason to create 3 separate capture groups and then put them back together as a single string rather than just use 1 capture group. So it'd then be `s/^.*_vm-([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)-.*/vm-\1/'` or even `s/^.*_vm-(([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9]+)-.*/vm-\1/'`. Not my downvote btw.